# How to save the .List of a combobox to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to store all of the items from a combobox in a variable. What type should the variable be? I tried to make a

```
Dim ComboBoxItems() As String ' dynamic array of strings
```

but then I am not sure how to copy the items from the combobox into this dynamic array?

I can do it in a loop:

```
for i = 1 to combobox.ListCount - 1
 ComboBoxItems(i+1) = combobox.List(i)
next i
```

(note, am I right that it is really crazy and a dynamic array is 1-indexed while the combobox List is 0-indexed??)

Is this the way to go? Or surely there is a way to copy the entire list without a loop?

Comment: Is this in a `UserForm` or a Active / Forms control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an ActiveX ComboBox on a worksheet called `Combobox1` you could use:

```
Sub Test()
Dim vArr()
ReDim vArr(1 To ComboBox1.ListCount)
vArr = ComboBox1.List
End Sub
```

Same approach for a UserForm with a combobox `ComboBox1` and command button `CommandButton1`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim S()
ReDim S(1 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount)
S = Me.ComboBox1.List
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Load some items into ComboBox
With Me.ComboBox1
.AddItem "fred, jones'"
.AddItem "mary"
.AddItem "wayne"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so what type is that vArr()? String?

Comment: @daviddoria It is a Variant. In this case it picks up the array of items held by the `ComboBox`